# RSA Encryption using public key

Tags: ios, encryption, rsa

I am writing iOS Application. Server sends RSA public key to application. Now application has to encrypt some information using RSA algorithm

Kindly provide me some reference.
Thanks

Comment: Look at this question on how to encrypt with RSA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211484/send-rsa-public-key-to-iphone-and-use-it-to-encrypt

Comment: See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291609/encryption-with-rsa-public-key-on-ios/28291683#28291683

Answer (score 4):

iOS has no special API for RSA, but there are some APIs about Certificate. You can use these APIs to encrypt your data by RSA.

First, you must use openssl to generate your RSA private key and public key. The most important thing is that the public key must be signed. Here is a instruction to generate the keys.

```
openssl req -x509 -out public_key.der -outform der -new -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout private_key.pem -days 3650
```

However, if you already has a private key(.pem file), you can follow the instructions:

```
openssl req -new -out cert.csr -key private_key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in cert.csr -out public_key.der -outform der -signkey private_key.pem -days 3650
```

You can check the **public_key.der** by opening it in xcode.

When you get the correct **public_key.der** file, you can view the RSA.h and RSA.m [here](http://blog.iamzsx.me/show.html?id=155002). I'm sorry that I have no time to rewrite this post by English again.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!
Do you have the openssl code to retrieve the information encrypted with those keys?

Comment: hello, you told to generate keys with the certificate, but i have public key that is provided by the JAVA developer, so i want to decrypt message using that key...so how can i do that ?

Comment: I suppose your key is a string. Sorry that I don't know how to convert a string key to a file.

Answer (score 1):

This Pod encapsulates the encryption: https://github.com/xjunior/XRSA

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about iOS but the [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html) seems to be what you need. It appears the [SecKeyEncrypt](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157-CH1g-SW26) will be used by you at some point.

Comment: yes, To use this API, i need SecKeyRef of RSA public ey, which i have as NSSTring. I am not able to get it's SecKeyRef. I am using iOS 4.2

Comment: @macdev30, I am struggling with the same issue: encrypting with a NSString RSA public key. Did you manage to solve this?