# iOS/Objective C: Using SecKeyWrapper to encrypt/decrypt String/Data

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I want to do some RSA encryption on iPhone and after a bit of reading through iOS Developer library I found the CryptoExercise example code and its class "[SecKeyWrapper](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html)"...

Can anyone tell me, how to encrypt/decrypt an NSString or NSData with a generated key pair from this class..

I've read through the code, but I didn't understand everything...

Thank you in advance..

Comment: This question ([http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211484/send-rsa-public-key-to-iphone-and-use-it-to-encrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211484/send-rsa-public-key-to-iphone-and-use-it-to-encrypt)) has a good answer how to encrypt with RSA on iOS. It doesn't use the SecKeyWrapper class