# Implementing Asymmetric encryption for Objective C using Truststore

Tags: android, ios, encryption-asymmetric, truststore

I'm trying to do an encryption method for ios mobile platform(Objective C) which on android(Java) is using [this method](http://www.java-redefined.com/2013/11/asymmetric-key-encryptiondecryption.html)

Need guidance on how to apply that method for ios. Am not very sure on how to port it to xcode to use it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here is an example of RSA encryption in Objective-C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211484/send-rsa-public-key-to-iphone-and-use-it-to-encrypt?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could try having a look at this:

https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-crypto-ios

It's a nice wrapper over the underlying crypto functionalities in iOS.